# add and removing divs from a div while also toggling classes

Tags: toggle, addclass, removeclass

I have some block divs. 
when you click on div(this), it fades the other divs (toggleClass). 
When you click on that same div(this), it removes the 'fade' (toggleClass).

so what I am having troubles with is this.

if you click on a 'fade' div. 
I need that div to not 'fade' and all the other divs to 'fade'

so no matter what div you click on that one is not fading ever, and all the other divs fade. while also toggling the fade when you click on/off your (this) div

here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/misschohoh/AzDQm/264/

```
$(".block").click(function() {  
$('.block, .outlink').toggleClass('fade');
$( this ).removeClass('fade');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/AzDQm/275/

Is this what you were referring to?

```
$(".block,.outlink").click(function() {  
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){

        $( this ).removeClass('active');
        $('.block, .outlink').removeClass('fade');
        return;
    }
    $('.block, .outlink').removeClass('active');
    $('.block, .outlink').addClass('fade');
    $( this ).removeClass('fade');
    $( this ).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/jasonhulbert/pen/JYZMzW

```
$('.block, .outlink').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('fade').siblings().addClass('fade');
});
```

Of course, this expects all your 'blocks' and 'outlinks' to be siblings

And if you're using a version of jquery that doesn't include the .on() method, you can simply swap in .bind():

```
$('.block, .outlink').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('fade').siblings().addClass('fade');
});
```